# Why does my implementation of merge sort in Python not work

Tags: python, mergesort

Here's my implementation of merge sort in Python which does not work:

```
def merge_sort(data: list) -> list:
    if len(data) > 1:
        mid = len(data) // 2
        L = data[:mid]
        R = data[mid:]

        merge_sort(L)
        merge_sort(R)

        # merge two halves
        data = merge(L, R)

def merge(L, R):
    i = j = k = 0
    temp = []
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            temp.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(R[j])
            j += 1
        k += 1
    temp[k:] = L[i:] + R[j:]
    return temp
```

However, a small change would make it work

```
def merge_sort(data: list) -> list:
    if len(data) > 1:
        mid = len(data) // 2
        L = data[:mid]
        R = data[mid:]

        merge_sort(L)
        merge_sort(R)

        # changes here
        merge(data, L, R)

def merge(data: list, L, R):
    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            data[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            data[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    data[k:] = L[i:] + R[j:]
```

I feel the two implementations are basically the same and I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what is wrong with the first implementation and how it is different from the second implementation.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: `-> list` is incorrect for both versions. Maybe you forgot `return data` in the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `merge_sort` function *ignores* the return value of `merge`; as written, it requires a `merge` function that sorts its argument in-place, rather than returning a new list.

Note that because the working `merge` takes the entire list as an argument, you don't need to construct sublists to merge; it would be sufficient to pass the lower and upper indices that *define* the sublist to sort. Then you would use `L` and `R` in place of `len(L)` and `len(R)` (with suitable adjustments to the starting values of `i`, `j`, and `k`).

Comment: I do realise the first implementation does not merge in place. But what I don't understand is that since I have data = merge(L, R), it should be equivalent to merge in place?

Comment: No, that just makes the *name* `data` refer to a new list, leaving the list actually passed as an argument unchanged.

Comment: @Misaka in your first code, by setting `data` to the return value of `merge`, which is `temp`, which was defined by `temp = []`, that means that `data` now points to a different list. So, all of the other ongoing calls to `merge_sort` are pointing to different lists. In the second example, everything is always pointing to the same list.